# Specific Background based on time

Tags: javascript, time, background-image

before start :

- yes, I googled and tryed many different solutions but they didn't works.
- I've limited knowledge on this, so be patients, can't do this alone.
- The website I'm talking about : http://animevid-main.webflow.com/

CUT

So, basically I'm asking you if you could help me adapting this code to change the background image of the div "blur_background" instead of changing color to the body background.
Other solutions are welcome, hope to solve this :)

EDIT :
Thats what i tryed, similar to your :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var currentTime = new Date().getHours();
    if(5 < currentTime && currentTime < 18){
            document.getElementsByClassName("blur_background")[0].style.background-image = 'http://adventureofucm.com/OtherSites/Day_Time_Background/imperial_boy_2800x1600_wallpap_2800x1600_.jpg';
    }
else{
            document.getElementsByClassName("blur_background")[0].style.background-image = 'http://adventureofucm.com/OtherSites/Day_Time_Background/1245989002801.jpg';
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please dont create  elements and make it super complicated. You can set styles of elements using javascript itself, for eg:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("blur_background")[0].style.backgroundColor ='red'
```

will change the color to red for your div.

Try that code in your website and it changes background color. So you can conditionally trigger this statement instead of document.write

UPDATE: To set backgorund-image use this

```
document.getElementsByClassName("blur_background")[0].style.backgroundImage = 'url(http://adventureofucm.com/OtherSites/Day_Time_Background/imperial_boy_2800x1600_wallpap_2800x1600_.jpg)';
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, i tryed something like this but it didnt's work, edited the post with the script i tryed that didn't work.

Comment: use this `document.getElementsByClassName("blur_background")[0].style.backgroundImage = 'url(http://adventureofucm.com/OtherSites/Day_Time_Background/imperial_boy_2800x1600_wallpap_2800x1600_.jpg)';`

Comment: meh, probably it's just me doing something wrong, think I'll give up :/ thanks for your help

Comment: so yeah, it's just me doing it wrong i presume, maybe it's cause put the code in the div "html_code" ?

Answer (score 0):

In css you can use `background-image: url("[YOUR IMAGE URL HERE]")` to change your background to image

In your case, you can change the background when it's 18-19 in the night like this:

```
//18-19 night
if (hours > 17 && hours < 20){
        document.write('body{background-image: url("[YOUR IMAGE URL HERE]"); color:#FFFFFF;} a{color: yellow !important}')
}
```

Here are resources to help you out with other options in changing an element's background:

[W3SCHOOLS css background](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp)

[W3SCHOOLS css image background](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp)